# If the amount of stack memory provided to a program is fixed then why does it grow downwards in the process architecture? Or am I getting it wrong?

Tags: process, operating-system, ram, stack-memory, main-memory

So I read that when a program is loaded on the main memory , it asscociates along with it static data , stack memory and heap memory. Wherein the stack generally grows downwards while the heap grows upwards. What I am confused about is since the stack is fixed in size how can it grow in the first place?

Comment: The stack *usage* grows in accordance with method calls.

Comment: @user207421 , so does that mean , the stack memory is not constant or fixed in size?

Comment: The stack doesn't grow but its usage does. On Linux, the stack has a fixed of 8MB by default. Its usage by the process may grow but not its size.

Comment: @user123 does heap also behave simillarly?