# what is the use of attaching static data along with a program when it is loaded on the main memory?

Tags: memory-management, process, operating-system, loader, stack-memory

When the operating system loads Program onto the main memory , it , along with the stack and heap memory , also attaches the static data along with it. I googled about what is present in the static data which said it contained the global variables and static variables. But I am confused as both of these are already present in the text file of the program then why do we add them seperately?

Answer (score 0):

The data in the executable is often referred as the data segment. The CPU doesn't interact with the hard-disk but only with RAM. The data segment must thus be loaded in RAM before the CPU can access it. The file of the executable is not really a text file. It is an executable so it has a different extension. Text files often refer to an actual file with a .txt extension.

With that said, you also asked another question not long ago ([If the amount of stack memory provided to a program is fixed then why does it grow downwards in the process architecture? Or am I getting it wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71669639/if-the-amount-of-stack-memory-provided-to-a-program-is-fixed-then-why-does-it-gr)) so I will try to give some insight for both of these in this same answer.

I don't know much about caching and low level inner CPU workings but, today mostly, the CPU doesn't even operate on RAM directly. It will load a bunch of RAM chunks into the cache and make operations on them and keep RAM-cache consistency by implementing complex mechanisms. The OS also has its role to play in RAM-cache consistency but, like I said, I am far from an expert here. Other than that, caching is mostly transparent to the OS. The CPU handles it and the OS simply provides instructions to the CPU which executes them.

Today, you have paging used by most OS and implemented on most CPU architectures. With paging, every process sees a full contiguous virtual address space. The virtual address space is accessed contiguously and the hardware MMU translates those addresses to physical ones automatically by crossing the page tables. The OS is responsible to make sure the page tables are consistent and the MMU does the rest of the job (for more info read: [What is paging exactly? OSDEV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67033820/what-is-paging-exactly-osdev/67038488#67038488)). If you understand paging well, things become much clearer.

For a process, there is mostly 3 types of memory. There is the stack (often called automatic storage), the heap and the static/global data. I will attempt to give precision on all of these to give a global picture.

The stack is given a maximum size when the process begins. The OS handles that and creates the page tables and places the proper address in the stack pointer register so that stack accesses reach the proper region of physical memory. The stack is automatic storage which means that it isn't handled manually by the high level programmer. For example, in C/C++, the stack is managed by the compiler which, at the entry of a function, will create a stack frame and place offsets from the stack base pointer in the instructions. Every local variable (within a function) will be accessed with a relative negative offset from the stack base pointer. What the compiler needs to do is to create a stack frame of the proper size so that there will be enough place for all local variables of a particular function (for more info on the stack see: [Each program allocates a fixed stack size? Who defines the amount of stack memory for each application running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69623703/each-program-allocates-a-fixed-stack-size-who-defines-the-amount-of-stack-memor/69633252#69633252)).

For the heap, the OS reserves a very big amount of virtual memory. Today, virtual memory is very big (2^48 bytes or more). The amount of heap available for each process is often only limited by the amount of physical memory available to back virtual memory allocations. For example, a process could use `malloc()` to allocate 4KB of memory in C. The OS will be called with a system call by the libc library which is an implementation of the C standard library. The OS will then reserve a page of the virtual memory available for the heap and change the page tables so that accessing that portion of virtual memory will translate to somewhere in RAM (probably somewhere another process wasn't already using).

The static/global data are simply placed in the executable in the data segment. The data segment is loaded in the virtual memory alongside the text segment. The text segment will thus be able to access this data often using RIP-relative addressing.